# R CMD check NOTE: `No visible binding for global variable`, when defining a variable in an S3 generic and using it in a method

Tags: r, package, cran

Consider the following piece of code:

```r
greet <- function(object) {
        greeting <- "hola"
        UseMethod("greet", object)
}

greet.character <- function(object)
        paste(greeting, object)

greet("stackoverflow")
#> [1] "hola stackoverflow"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Evidently, the execution environment of `greet.character` method is populated with the variables created in the generic, before `UseMethod()`, so that the code works as expected.

However, including these definitions in a package will lead to the following NOTE upon R CMD check:

```
> checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  greet.character: no visible binding for global variable ‘greeting’
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    greeting
```

You can find an example package illustrating the issue at [this repository](https://github.com/vgherard/globalReprex).

Now, I am aware that I can shut up the NOTE with `globalVariables()`, but I am still puzzled about the origin of the NOTE in the first place. So my questions are:

1. Is there any intrinsic reason why the example above should be considered "bad practice" in an R package? In a real life example, I'm using a construct like this to avoid code repetition in several methods.
2. If not, is there any better option than using `globalVariables()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself, I think this practice can lead to confusing behaviour since `UseMethod()` generates a call of the appropriate method with its same arguments; implying that modifications to a variable which *is* an argument of the generic (not like `greeting` in my example above) are not propagated to the method.

Right now I'm defining extra functions to be called at the beginning of each method to perform the complex computation I was originally doing in the generic. This can also lead to cumbersome code if these functions require many arguments, but is the best solution I have found so far.

I will leave this open for some time to see if someone has other approaches to propose.